# position Images on the circle path with the given radius (SVG or PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, svg

I need to create an application which user enter radius of the curve or circle and choose the selected images (PNG Images with transparent background) will transform over the curve.

ex. here are the images:

[image: A]
[image: D]
[image: flower]

and user enter the radis of 100px in the textfield and submit, then the result will be:

[image: final result]

the images position in the center of the curve or circle. any idea and sample code will be helpful,(in javascript and svg or in php)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this previous StackOverflow question: [Align objects to curve with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761896/align-objects-to-curve-with-canvas)

It links to [a JavaScript library for help with the math](http://mathext.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: tnx , but i already checked that post and i tried many ways but didnt worked :((

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. No one is going to write it for you.

Comment: @PFK - precisely how didn't it work? "Doesn't work" is never a good answer to this question `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's jQuery Roundrr, http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/roundrr/ 
You can build something that users can select the parameters (like radius, etc), select the images, order ...
 and than pass the data to the PHP and generate the final image.